# NodeGit - resolve merge conflict in favor of "theirs"

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, nodegit

In git we can use following command to achieve it:

```
git merge branch_name --strategy-option theirs
```

But I couldn't figure out a way in nodegit: http://www.nodegit.org/api/repository/#mergeBranches

```
 repo.mergeBranches("master.min", "master", null, merge.PREFERENCE.FASTFORWARD_ONLY);
```

A file favor enum is present

http://www.nodegit.org/api/merge/#FILE_FAVOR

But `repo.mergeBranches()` expects `PREFERENCE` enum. How do I pass `FILE_FAVOR` enum for merge.

**Edit:** Adding a tracking issue:

https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/issues/858

Answer (score 1):

For now (January 2015), you don't.

The way [`Repository.prototype.mergeBranches` (`lib/repository.js#L730-L745`)](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/blob/232dbb19116c58d22cd7afd7435ee0bbe063f85b/lib/repository.js#L730-L745) is implemented, it doesn't take into account any FILE_FAVOR option (used by [their vendored libgit2](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/blob/08564a763432bdf08765e48733056ed309af4eb3/vendor/libgit2/src/merge.c#L1845)).

That could be the topic of a PR (Pull Request) similar to [PR 633](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/pull/633) (which introduced the options  `--no-ff` and `--ff-only`)

Comment: So you mean their is no way I can merge the two branches avoiding resolving conflicts manually

Comment: I tried deleting the modified and deleted files, committing them and then merging the other branch in the current branch but still it conflicts. Isn't there any way out?

Comment: Can't we programitically resolve conflict using theirs in the catch statement

Comment: @adnankamili that I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot using the repo.mergeBranches function as of now (although I'll make an issue so we can fix that), but if you look at the source for repo.mergeBranches, you can see how we call into nodegit.merge more directly (mergebranches is a js convenience wrapper), which does take a mergeoptions allowing you to pass file preference and other enums (as of jan 2016).

Comment: Interesting, and more precise than my answer. +1